# Issue with Linq with 3 tier

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, 3-tier

I had created one .dbml file.
I want to do coding in 3 tier architecture.
Now I have one table like UserMaster in dbml file.
Can I use that UserMaster in my aspx.cs page? or I have to create properties and assign values in business logic?

Comment: Yes you can but I'd suggest to create a component to place business logic.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of separating into differnt layer is to bring some loosly coupling and  abstraction so that the UI layer wont know what database access technology you are using at the Data Access level. So i think you should not share the UserMaster table directly to the UI layer. You better read data from the data source and then fill your POCO classes and return that to your UI layer.

So i would create a method which return a List of User (object of your User Entity class) to do this. So if there is a change (you waant to map the DisplayName field from FirstName to some other field), You make change in one place (your data layer) and you will have this change in all the places where you call  this method.

Comment: I want to see one demo application with linq and 3 tier architecture. so can any one help me for that?